# The order of cout messages is not as expected

Tags: c++

I am confused with the output of below code when I execute it.

Code:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    cout<<"inside int add function"<<endl;
    return a+b;
}

float add(float a, float b)
{
    cout<<"inside float add function"<<endl;
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<add(10.0f,20.0f)<<endl<<add(20,50); 
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
inside int add function
inside float add function
30
70
```

I dont understand the order of cout messages are getting printed in console. But I expected the output of above program like below

```
inside float add function
30
inside int add function
70
```

Could someone explain about above behavior.

Comment: It looks like the compiler is just evaluating both functions before performing the `cout`. So you're seeing it run the int add function, then the float add function, *then* the `cout`.

Comment: It's a sort of compiler optimization, it's the same as `return Something(getWhatever(), getWhatever());` the compiler sometimes will swap both calls.

Comment: Is there some reason you think one output is *required* over the other? It's certainly reasonable to expect what you claim to expect. But the compiler is free to do something different than we expect unless we insist that it not. Is there some reason you think the result you got is prohibited? Surely if you do `add(1,2)+add(1.0,2.0)`, the calls to `add` can occur in either order, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line in you code:

```
cout<<add(10.0f,20.0f)<<endl<<add(20,50);
```

will be translated by the compiler into:

```
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout,add(10.0f,20.0f)),endl),add(20,50));
```

As the order of evaluation of function parameters is not mandated by the standard, it just happens that `add(20,50)` is evaluated before `operator<<(operator<<(cout,add(10.0f,20.0f)),endl)`.

Answer (score 1):

the line `cout<<add(10.0f,20.0f)<<endl<<add(20,50);` is expected to print your output:

```
inside int add function
inside float add function
30
70
```

Thats because to print to `cout` firstly calls `add(10.0f , 20.0f)` and stores the output to a internal variable, then calls `add(10, 20)` and stores the output to another internal variable, and finally it prints the returned values. Something like this:

```
float a = add(10.0f, 20.0f);
int b = add(10, 20);
cout << a << endl << b;
```

In this case, if you want to print as you wish, try to print first one function, and then the other:

```
cout << add(10.0f, 20.0f) << endl;
cout << add(10, 20);
```

Comment: Not another internal variable, it can be the same as the other one, compiler is free to choose whether the 2nd call is to be the first or 1st to be 2nd and so on.  Also, it's not "internal", it's just how the generated assembly looks like, so if it stores the first one in an "internal" variable and decides that 2nd one is to be printed after the 1st one, then it'll be something like `mov REG, std::ostream; USE OPERATOR<< on REG FOR 1ST, USE OPERATOR<< ON REG FOR 2ND`

Comment: I know that "internal variable" is called register, but I called this way to not enter in the complicated world of assembly

Comment: It could've been better if you explained using C++ code, like `std::ostream& out; out << a; out << b;`