# Opposite outcome than expected with static variable (C++)

Tags: c++, static

I have this small programm:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f ();
int g();

int main () {
    cout << f() << f() << g();
}

int f () {
    static int zahl = 3;
    return ++zahl;
}

int g () {
    return f();
}
```

It prints out 654, but I expected 456, and I have no idea why it does that. Can anyone explain?

Comment: The order of evaluation is unspecified in C++: the compiler is free to execute the calls to `f()` and `g()` in any order it wants.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll have to put in seperate lines then, or is there a other way to do it?

Comment: Related: [The order of cout messages is not as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309153/the-order-of-cout-messages-is-not-as-expected), [C++: The order of std::cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123196/c-the-order-of-stdcout), [cout << order of call to functions it prints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129230/cout-order-of-call-to-functions-it-prints)

Comment: @ecatmur: although it is unlikely that `g()` would be evaluated between the two calls to `f()` I'm not aware of any constraint restricting the possible order of function parameter evaluations. I don't think there is a restriction that arguments to a nested function call are evaluated together.